# How to preserve referencies when Component is exported via a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, i18next

Documentation describes how to [add a ref to a class component](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-class-component) when using **ReactJS** version 16.3+.

Here is a simplified and working example using two files:

**MyForm.js file:**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MyInput from "./MyInput";

class MyForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.myInput = React.createRef();
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  onClick(){
    console.log(this.myInput.current.isValid());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyInput ref={this.myInput} />
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Verify form</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyForm;
```

**MyInput.js file**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyInput extends Component {

  isValid(){
    return true;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Name :
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyInput;
```

It works fine, console displays `true` when I click on `MyForm` button. But as soon as I add a function just before exporting my Component, errors are thrown. As example, I add a translation via react-i18n

**MyInput.js file with export using a function**

```
class MyInput extends Component {

  isValid(){
    return true;
  }

  render() {
    const {t} = this.props; 
    return (
      <div>
        {t("Name")}
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default translate()(MyInput); // <=== This line is changing
```

Now, when I click on button, an error is thrown:

> TypeError: this.myInput.current.isValid is not a function

The error disappear when I remove `translate()` in the last line.

I understood that the ref has been destroyed by the new component returned by translate function. It's an HOC. I read the [Forwarding ref chapter](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html), but I don't understand how to forward ref to the component returned by translate() function.

I have this problem as soon as I use `translate` from **reacti18next** and with the result of `connect` function from **redux**

I found [a solution using onRef props](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/909) and ComponentDidMount, but some contributors thinks this is an antipattern and I would like to avoid this.

Is there a way to create a wrapper that catch the HOC result of translate() or connect() and add ref to this HOC result ?

Comment: Why are you hard-coding a `MyInput` in the form instead of just rendering children?

Comment: I think it has to with options of i18next, [this](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/src/translate.js#L64) shows that refs are going to be passed if the option `withRef` is set to true. [This line](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/src/translate.js#L52) explains it. Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: JaredSmith : This MyInput is a very simplified example, not my code.
@seethrough : I tested it, this.inputText.current.isValid is still undefined,